# Python requests library doesn't always send data

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have a simple webserver running on an RPi Pico W which just displays the input message and sends back JSON. I'm able to access and retrieve data via a web browser and with cURL. However, when I try to access through Python's `requests`, most of the time there's no data being passed to it.

Driver code for making the request:

```py
import json
import requests

data = json.dumps({"KEY":"VALUE"})
res = requests.put("http://webserver.ip:port", data=data)
print(res.json())
```

Code on the Pico W to accept connections:

```py
i = 0
while True:
    client = conn.accept()[0]
    print(f"[{i}] Client connected: {client}")
    msg = client.recv(8192)
    print(f"Message: {msg}")
    data = msg.decode("utf-8").split("\r")[-1].strip()
    print(f'Data: {data}, {type(data)}, {data == ""}')
    message = {
        "data": ujson.loads(data) if data != "" else None,
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
    }
    client.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
    client.send(b"Content-Type: application/json\n")
    client.send(b"Connection: keep-alive\n\n")
    client.sendall(ujson.dumps(message).encode("utf-8"))
    client.close()
    i += 1
```

On the Pico, after processing the input message, I set a key in the response `data` to be the data passed in; if there is no data passed in, I set it to `None`. I expect the above request to send back:

```json
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "data": {"KEY":"VALUE"}}
```

but instead I get:

```json
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "data": None}
```

Running the same request with cURL *does* give me the expected response.

---

**My question is:** why is it that data isn't being sent with the request? I'm not quite sure what's causing the actual data to be empty when reaching the Pico.

It's all powered by simple sockets, so there's not too much complexity with getting the message. Changing the kwarg in the driver code from `data=data` to `json=data` also doesn't help (this assumes I'm sending a dict rather than a JSON string).

Comment: `print(f"Message: {msg}")` What does this show?

Comment: May I ask why you are using your own http server implementation? You will run into SOO many problems down the road. How will you handle headers? Websockets?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a single call to `.recv()` is going to return the entire content of the request, regardless of the buffer size you specify - it's going to return as soon as *any* data has been received from the network.  Apparently, `requests` has enough of a delay between sending the headers and the body that you receive them separately, but cURL sends it all together.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I have the Pico and wanted to make one. Not much else to it. Since it's a Pico, I don't have to worry about general use case, so I can tailor it to my specific uses which aren't all that complex (yet).

Comment: @jasonharper That's incredibly interesting, I didn't know that. I would test this immediately on my Pico if I had it with me, but would I then be able to call `.recv()` until there's no longer any data being received? Instead of doing it once

Comment: That makes sense. As JasonHarper said, you have a lot to do with regards to understanding TCP sockets. You will have to read a lot on http, and tcp. Your response just now while I was writing would be the correct way of doing it. The only problem is knowing when it ends.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I have a million tabs open right now so definitely lots of reading!

Comment: Yeah! I would recommend Wikipedia for a basic rundown, but eventually you may need to read documents called “RFC”s. These are the bread and butter of networking documentation. Many are decades old, and they are all plain text documents. Nevertheless, it is a good way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've fixed it for now! Thanks to @jasonharper for the insight. It was in fact because there's no guarantee that all of the message will have been sent when I run `client.recv()`. Thus, I added a retry based on the content length.

```py
def serve(conn):
    i = 0
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        client = conn.accept()[0]
        print(f"[{i}] Client connected: {client}")
        msg = client.recv(4096)
        print(f"Message: {msg}")
        headers, data = process_message(msg)
        if ("Content-Length" in headers and
            int(headers["Content-Length"]) > len(data)):
            mtmp = client.recv(4096)
            _, dtmp = process_message(mtmp)
            data = dtmp
        print(f'Data: {data}, {type(data)}, {data == ""}')
        print(f'Headers: {headers}')
        message = {
            "data": ujson.loads(data) if data != "" else None,
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
        }
        client.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
        client.send(b"Content-Type: application/json\n")
        client.send(b"Connection: keep-alive\n\n")
        client.sendall(ujson.dumps(message).encode("utf-8"))

        client.close()
        i += 1
```

I needed a way to reliably get `Content-Length`, so I wrote this to process the received message:

```py
def process_message(message):
    message_dict = {
        "Info": [],
    }
    message_split = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), message.decode("utf-8").split("\r")))
    headers = message_split[:-1]
    body = message_split[-1]
    for i in headers:
        if i == "":
            continue
        key_value = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), i.split(":")))
        if len(key_value) < 2:
            message_dict["Info"] += key_value
            continue
        message_dict[key_value[0]] = key_value[1]
    return message_dict, body
```

And now it works! Running the driver code from my question gets the expected response.

**[2024-3-27] [Edit]** Looking at this code again, I was stumped why `process_message` looked so dense and tedious. Just have to keep in mind that on input, we're receiving *bytes*, thus we have to do string processing to get the data out. There's a probably a better way to accomplish what I'm doing here.